# Why I can't retrieve a local registry entry value from a WSO2 ESB API?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to use the WSO2 **Local Registry** into an ESB project.

So in my EI project I have added this **env.xml** file into the **local-entries** folder (and then I have add it to Maven to be included in the project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="env" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">TEST</localEntry>
```

So in theory I am defining a **locaEntry** having **key="env"** and the textual strin **TEST** as value.

Now I am trying to retrieve it into an **ESB** REST API, following the official documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Local+Registry+Entries) I am trying to retrieve it with the **get-property(prop-name)** function (where **prop-name** should be the defined key: **env** in my case).

Into my API code I have this:

```
<inSequence>
    <log level="full"/>
    <property expression="get-property('uri.var.countryId')" name="countryId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property expression="get-property('uri.var.lang_id')" name="lang_id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:countryId" name="Country ID"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:lang_id" name="Lang ID"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:env" name="env"/>
    </log>
    .........................................................................
    .........................................................................
    .........................................................................
```

As you can see I am trying to retrieve and log the content of my **env** local entry but this is waht I am obtaining into the WSO2 log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-07-05 12:36:44,055]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  
Country ID = 1, 
Lang ID = 1, 
env = <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Local Entries there are two types which you can mention

```
1. Inline Text

2. Inline XML.
```

As i see that you are using inline XML as it's ending with .xml(While creating XML can needn't have to specify the extension `.xml` as you will already be selecting `inline XML`), if this is the case then use the below property

```
 <property
        expression="get-property('env')"
        name="Indexing" scope="default" type="OM" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>.
```

So your local entry should look like

```
<ROOT_ELEMENT>
Test
</ROOT_ELEMENT>
```

After this in your sequence use log mediator for the property `$ctx:indexing`